# Oracle tree: Predecessor and follower with some omissions

Tags: sql, oracle, tree

I would like to get help for a recursive query. The use of "Connect by prior" is new to me and I have a some difficulty using it.

I’m looking for a way to get a list of data classified by connectivity (parent-child relation), while omitting some type of records in Oracle 11gR2. In other words, I have a tree like structure and I want a new tree where some invalid data will be omited.

For example, here is the information I have in my table which I call "OriginalSequence"

```
WITH OriginalSequence AS
(
SELECT 'ID1' AS KEY, 'INVALID1' AS CHILD, NULL AS PARENT FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'INVALID1'  , 'ID2'              , 'ID1'          FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'INVALID1'  , 'ID3'              , 'ID1'          FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'ID2'       , 'INVALID2'         , 'INVALID1'     FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'ID3'       , 'ID4'              , 'INVALID1'     FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'ID3'       , 'INVALID3'         , 'INVALID1'     FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'INVALID2'  , NULL               , 'ID2'          FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'ID4'       , NULL               , 'ID3'          FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'INVALID3'  , 'ID5'              , 'ID3'          FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'INVALID3'  , 'INVALID4'         , 'ID3'          FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'ID5'       , 'ID6'              , 'INVALID3'     FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'INVALID4'  , 'ID7'              , 'INVALID3'     FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'ID6'       , NULL               , 'ID5'          FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'ID7'       , 'ID8'              , 'INVALID4'     FROM dual union ALL
SELECT 'ID8'       , NULL               , 'ID7'          FROM dual
)
```

IMPORTANT: Even if my example shows the contrary, data from my "real" table are NOT sorted in order of connectivity.

In my table "OriginalSequence":

- The column "KEY" is the name of the current key.
- The column "Child" is the key name after the current key.
- The column "Parent" is the name of the key before the current key.
- Is considered "invalid" a key starting with "INVALID".

Hierarchically, the data from my example resemble this:
 http://i.xomf.com/qlkgx.png

So I'd like a way to omit (skip over) invalid data in order to have the following result:

```
KEY,NEW_CHILD,NEW_PARENT
ID1,ID2      ,null
ID1,ID3      ,null
ID2,null     ,ID1
ID3,ID4      ,ID1
ID3,ID5      ,ID1
ID3,ID7      ,ID1
ID4,null     ,ID3
ID5,ID6      ,ID3
ID6,null     ,ID5
ID7,ID8      ,ID3
ID8,null     ,ID7
```

http://i.xomf.com/dfsdq.png

Ideally I would like to avoid the PL/SQL and stay in SQL, but if there is no way around it, I will take the PL/SQL solution!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH invalid_removed AS (
  -- remove the invalid entries
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT parent AS key,
         child
  FROM   OriginalSequence
  WHERE  child NOT LIKE 'INVALID%'
  OR     child IS NULL
  CONNECT BY PRIOR child = key
             AND key LIKE 'INVALID%'
  START WITH (   parent IS null
              OR parent NOT LIKE 'INVALID%'
             )
             AND key LIKE 'INVALID%'

UNION ALL

  -- include the rows which are not invalid
  SELECT key,
         child
  FROM   OriginalSequence
  WHERE  key NOT LIKE 'INVALID%'
  AND    (child NOT LIKE 'INVALID%'
          OR child IS NULL)

UNION ALL

  -- include the root (if not included by first query)
  SELECT parent AS key,
         key AS child
  FROM   OriginalSequence
  WHERE  parent IS NULL
  AND    key NOT LIKE 'INVALID%'
)
SELECT key,
       child,
       PRIOR key AS parent
FROM   invalid_removed
CONNECT BY PRIOR child = key
START WITH key IS NULL
ORDER BY key ASC NULLS FIRST, child ASC NULLS FIRST;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd35e/39/0)

Comment: Oh my god, it works! Thank you very much for the quick reply! I worked on this request for a long time without any success... You make my day!